logger.exception during context-manager __exit__
How do I call logger.exception during context-manager __exit__?
My context manager class definition is:
import logging
from types import TracebackType
from typing import Optional, Type


class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.log = logging.getLogger("B")

    def __exit__(
        self,
        exc_type: Optional[Type[BaseException]],
        exc_inst: Optional[BaseException],
        exc_tb: Optional[TracebackType],
    ) -> bool:
        if exc_inst is not None:
            self.log.exception("EXCEPTION!")
            return False  # let exception propagate
        return True

Do I need to explicitly pass arguments to self.log.exception so it prints the exception information and traceback?

Related but not the same questions What are the python builtin exit argument types?, Log exception with traceback in Python

Did you try it? What happened?

Another related but not the same question Re-assign exception from within a python __exit__ block


show desired output; 2) structlog library is a bit advanced and you can assign exception instance to keyword "exc_info" in logger, so it will log full traceback


No, you do not have to pass the exception details explicitly to log.exception, it will pick them up automatically.
Example:
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger()


class Context:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_inst, exc_tb):
        if exc_inst is not None:
            logger.exception("exit")
        print("cleanup")
        return True


def run(fail: bool):
    print("before")
    with Context():
        if fail:
            raise RuntimeError("it failed")
    print("after")

>>> run(fail=True)
before
ERROR:root:exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/fail.py", line 22, in run
    raise RuntimeError("it failed")
RuntimeError: it failed
cleanup
after

>>> run(fail=False)
before
cleanup
after


No special arguments are necessary for logger.exception; just call self.log.exception("EXCEPTION!").
import logging
from types import TracebackType
from typing import Optional, Type


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.log = logging.getLogger("B")
        self.log.info("Init B")

    def __enter__(self):
        self.log.info("Entering B")
        return self

    def __exit__(
        self,
        exc_type: Optional[Type[BaseException]],
        exc_inst: Optional[BaseException],
        exc_tb: Optional[TracebackType],
    ) -> bool:
        self.log.info("Exiting B")
        if exc_inst is not None:
            self.log.exception("EXCEPTION!")
            # return False  # let exception propagate
        return True


def main():
    with B() as _:
        print("no exception")

    with B() as _:
        raise RuntimeError("BLARG!!!!!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    main()

prints
INFO:B:Init B
INFO:B:Entering B
no exception
INFO:B:Exiting B
INFO:B:Init B
INFO:B:Entering B
INFO:B:Exiting B
ERROR:B:EXCEPTION!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\try1.py", line 34, in main
    raise RuntimeError("BLARG!!!!!")
RuntimeError: BLARG!!!!!

If return False occurs from __exit__ then the exception may be printed again by an outer exception handler.
